# Git Submodule Path issues

Tags: php, git

I've recently made a mistake and typed out `rm -rf .git/modules` while testing  some absolute paths which took away all of my git commands such as `git status`.

How can I recover that back? Below, is the error that I am receiving:

> sm----@US3FHIM0XQ86TJG: ~/Sites/----------.com/sites/htdocs[develop*]$
>
> git status fatal: not a git repository: wordpress/../.git/modules/wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by reseting all git-submodules with

```
rm -rf .git/modules
git submodule update --init
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lsof` to recover the files

https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c00833030